# Impossible to use keras in R

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have been trying to install Keras in R. Previously I have done that in another machine , it worked well there, but now i am facing problems.

Codes:

```
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("rstudio/reticulate")
devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras")
devtools::install_github("rstudio/tensorflow")

install_keras()
```

All worked well, but when i am trying to load any inbuilt dataset or run in keras  functions its giving me error like this.(along with a dialog box : rssesion.exe Entry point not found)

```
image=image_load(" D:/CT images/image1.png")  

Error in image_load(" D:/CT images/image1.png") : 
The Pillow Python package is required to load images  

> mnist <- dataset_mnist()
Error: C:/Users/user/ANACON~1/envs/R-TENS~1/python36.dll - The specified 
procedure could not be found.
```

I have checked the output of :

reticulate::py_discover_config("keras")

reticulate::py_discover_config("tensorflow")

Output :

```
> reticulate::py_discover_config("keras")
python:         C:\Users\user\ANACON~1\envs\R-TENS~1\python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/user/ANACON~1/envs/R-TENS~1/python36.dll
pythonhome:     C:\Users\user\ANACON~1\envs\R-TENS~1
version:        3.6.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jun 28 2018, 11:27:44) [MSC 
v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:\Users\user\ANACON~1\envs\R-TENS~1\lib\site-packages\numpy
numpy_version:  1.14.3
keras:          [NOT FOUND]

python versions found: 
C:\Users\user\ANACON~1\envs\R-TENS~1\python.exe
C:\Users\user\ANACON~1\python.exe
C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\python.exe
C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\r-tensorflow\python.exe

> reticulate::py_discover_config("tensorflow")
python:         C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\r-tensorflow\python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/user/Anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/python36.dll
pythonhome:     C:\Users\user\ANACON~1\envs\R-TENS~1
version:        3.6.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jun 28 2018, 11:27:44) [MSC 
v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:\Users\user\ANACON~1\envs\R-TENS~1\lib\site-packages\numpy
numpy_version:  1.14.3
tensorflow:     C:\Users\user\ANACON~1\envs\R-TENS~1\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow\__init__.p

python versions found: 
C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\r-tensorflow\python.exe
C:\Users\user\ANACON~1\envs\R-TENS~1\python.exe
C:\Users\user\ANACON~1\python.exe
C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\python.exe
```

I have installed the latest version of Anaconda and also installed latest version of R and Rstudio.
I cant understand the problem since I am a beginner. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install and use Keras in R using the following commands. I haven't faced any issues.

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras")

library(keras)

install_keras()
```